# Joomla not logging PHP errors to file with system default error_reporting

Tags: joomla-3.x, php7, error-reporting

I'm using Joomla 3.9 with APACHE + PHP 7.0 with these settings

```
php_flag[display_errors] = On
php_flag[display_startup_errors] = On
php_value[error_reporting] = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE
php_flag[html_errors] = On
php_admin_flag[ignore_repeated_errors] = Off
php_flag[log_errors] = On
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = On
php_value[log_errors_max_len] = 1024
```

When Joomla `error_reporting` is set to `development`, errors are shown on the site and also logged in the error log file. When error_reporting is set to `default` it should still do the same since according to the documentation"

> “System Default” leaves the level of PHP error reporting to that set up in the server (usually in the php.ini file).

However nothing is shown OR logged. If I create a test.php on the root of site (so that it bypasses the Joomla core) with an error -- that error *is* logged so the PHP settings are working correctly.

Is Joomla doing something else or could this be a bug?

Comment: FYI, [PHP7.1 and below are no longer supported](https://www.php.net/eol.php).  You should bring your php version up to at least 7.2.  I have no idea if this will solve your issue, but this needs to be on your TODO list either way.

Comment: The upgrade is exactly why I need the log -- to see why sites don't open with 7.4 but anyway this also happened when I tried with 7.4 so the PHP version shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: Joomla is checking the PHP ini file settings on displaying error messages with this line: `if (ini_get('display_errors')) {…};` . Thus most probably if you set error display in a `.htaccess` file, it is going to be ignored by Joomla. So the `php.ini` file should be modified for getting what you need, or with creating a custom `php.ini` file.

Comment: I’m not sure that it has anything to do with PHP error logging though.

Comment: these values are set in PHP FPM configuration

Comment: Your first port of call should be to check the PHP settings (note this is literally just a call to `php_info();` at `administrator/index.php?option=com_admin&view=sysinfo`. This is what Joomla is using to determine what to do with your errors - as alluded to by @Zollie

Comment: @SandroAntonucci - yes, I see, PHP FPM configuration overrides the `php.ini` settings at error displaying and logging. However, as I see, the settings of Joomla error reporting (error displaying), in global config, does not influence “PHP error logging“.

Comment: More like "it shouldn't" because is definitely doing something.